# Redirecting stdout to QML QT Quick Control

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

In my QML app I am loading an external (shared object) library, which does a lot of printing to stdout. How would I redirect this stdout to a QT Quick Control 2 (say a ScrollView control) ? Right now it is printing everything to the application console, just like qWarning() does.

Just in case it matters, this library was created from Go sources compiling it into C shared library. I am loading it with a C++ class through a Q_INVOKABLE method, calling it from QML. I can not modify this library, or better said, I can, it has a Debug class which can be modified, but I don't know how to interface it with QT, it is written in Go language. I believe redirecting stdout to a QML control would be easier.

What can you suggest?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc it is going to be cross platform, so Android, IOS , Linux, and you name it.... Everything that Qt supports

Comment: If you go for qt's own debug warning and error outputs, you can easily use `qInstallMessageHandler()` to install your own handler that does with the output whatever you want. It will probably be more complex with stdout.

Comment: @dtech, I know, but the library is written in Go language and there is no qWarning() calls there. I would have to rewrite the entire library in C++, and it is a huge codebase, made by about 10 developers during 3 years

Comment: You can simply link against Qt libs and make a simple C wrapper API for using the Qt functionality. No need to rewrite anything, keep the C code and build it with a C compiler. Just do a find and replace to substitute existing output calls with the new one.

Comment: @dtech, well, the Go library has a `Log` object, which does all the logging. Do you mean I should replace this logging mechanism to send all the log to Qt? Because, I don't understand how would you do this only by linking. The Go library already sends everything to `stdout`, you can't make it to send logs to a wrapper without touching Go code.

Comment: Well, in that case its even easier, you will just have to change the implementation of the Log object.